# Atlassian SDK InvalidCastException when using LINQ expressions

Tags: vb.net, linq, jira

Let's start out by saying I'm not a terrifically experienced developer, so there is every possibility that I'm completely missing something here.

I'm implementing the [Atlassian.NET SDK](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/wiki/Home) in a VB .Net solution.  For the most part things work well, but I get the following error when I try to use the LINQ provider directly:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Atlassian.Jira.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>    'System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression' to type
>    'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression'.

The full exception:

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled   HResult=-2147467262
>   Message=Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression' to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression'.   Source=Atlassian.Jira 
>   StackTrace:
>          at Atlassian.Jira.Linq.JqlExpressionVisitor.GetFieldNameFromBinaryExpression(BinaryExpression
>   expression) in
>   c:\projects\atlassian-net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Linq\JqlExpressionVisitor.cs:line
>   65
>          at Atlassian.Jira.Linq.JqlExpressionVisitor.ProcessIndexedMemberEqualityOperator(BinaryExpression
>   expression, Boolean equal) in
>   c:\projects\atlassian-net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Linq\JqlExpressionVisitor.cs:line
>   142
>          at Atlassian.Jira.Linq.JqlExpressionVisitor.ProcessEqualityOperator(BinaryExpression
>   expression, Boolean equal) in
>   c:\projects\atlassian-net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Linq\JqlExpressionVisitor.cs:line
>   136
>          at Atlassian.Jira.Linq.JqlExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression
>   node) in
>   c:\projects\atlassian-net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Linq\JqlExpressionVisitor.cs:line
>   325
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
>   visitor)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1
>   node)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression
>   node)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
>   visitor)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitArguments(IArgumentProvider
>   nodes)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
>   node)
>          at Atlassian.Jira.Linq.JqlExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
>   node) in
>   c:\projects\atlassian-net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Linq\JqlExpressionVisitor.cs:line
>   252
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
>   visitor)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitArguments(IArgumentProvider
>   nodes)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
>   node)
>          at Atlassian.Jira.Linq.JqlExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
>   node) in
>   c:\projects\atlassian-net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Linq\JqlExpressionVisitor.cs:line
>   252
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
>   visitor)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>          at Atlassian.Jira.Linq.JqlExpressionVisitor.Process(Expression expression) in
>   c:\projects\atlassian-net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Linq\JqlExpressionVisitor.cs:line
>   42
>          at Atlassian.Jira.Linq.JiraQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression, Boolean isEnumerable) in
>   c:\projects\atlassian-net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Linq\JiraQueryProvider.cs:line
>   44
>          at Atlassian.Jira.Linq.JiraQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) in
>   c:\projects\atlassian-net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Linq\JiraQueryProvider.cs:line
>   39
>          at Atlassian.Jira.Linq.JiraQueryable`1.GetEnumerator() in c:\projects\atlassian-net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Linq\JiraQueryable.cs:line
>   29
>          at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable\`1 source)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at JiraUpdater.JiraStuff.GetIssueByDetail(String summary) in C:\Users\v709092\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\JiraUpdater\JiraUpdater\JiraStuff.vb:line 33
>          at JiraUpdater.Form1.ButtonMassUpdate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\v709092\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\JiraUpdater\JiraUpdater\Form1.vb:line 98
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
>   commandLine)
>          at JiraUpdater.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 81
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

My code is a straight forward conversion of sample code found on the project WIKI page.

```
    Dim myJira As Jira = Jira.CreateRestClient("JiraServer", "username", "password")

    Dim myIssueQuery = From i In myJira.Issues
                                Where i.Project = "JiraProjectName"
                                Select i

   Console.WriteLine( myIssueQuery.Count())
```

After doing some research I've become pretty convinced that this is an issue with how the LINQ provider is handling the query.  This [issue](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/issues/62/visual-basic) was reported to the developer a long while ago and marked as "Won't Fix" because the developer was not familiar with VB.

I'd really appreciate any assistance in either providing the developer relevant details to fix the issue on their side, or more realistically help pointing out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Api for Jira can get a little complex and it is easy to end up using an older one that won't do what you want.  I have had the best results using the nuget package "Atlassian.SDK".

With this it is relatively trivial to do what you want.  this is C# code but I guess the vb.net can't be much different.

```
 this.JiraConnection = Jira.CreateRestClient(jiraUrl, jiraUser, jiraPassword);
 string jql = "project = TC";
 IEnumerable<Issue> issues = this.JiraConnection.GetIssuesFromJql(jql, 100);
```

This allows you to use use the Jira Query Language to get the issues you want, which in my tests proved faster & more reliable than querying using Linq.

HTH

Comment: I am using the Atlassian.SDK v6.2.2 package from NuGet.  The GetIssuesFromJql method does indeed work which provides a nice work around for my main issue, thank you for that.